# How to web-scraping continually with python selenium, using URL lists in csv file

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I need to know how to web-scrape by using csv file. The file I have contains list of 'company name', 'homepage URL', 'address', and so on.

The thing I have to do is:

1. Scraping 'contact address(e-mail)' by using list of company's homepage URL.
2. Save as csv file.

I've tried to use pandas, selenium library.
Scraping one e-mail address from one URL was successful.

Here's the problem:

1. Each of homepage has different HTML structure
2. Can not find the way scraping continually
   (for-? while-?)

Comment: What is your specific problem, error you run into?

Comment: Even though it is obvious what you are referring to, it's spelled "scraping", with 1 p. "Scrapping", with 2 "P"s, has a completely different meaning. That could unfortunately be the reason you are not getting good results with your troubleshooting.

Comment: if every page has different structure then you have to create different code for every page. You can't create one universal code for all pages.

Comment: You can store your data in a `Pandas data-frame` and iterate over it, for web pages use `Beautiful Soup` to find elements with `Email tags, "email" in HTML .etc` using `regex` or `Beautiful Soup` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Python `csv` library to parse your file a row at a time and `beautifulsoup` to parse the HTML. From your question, your URL would be in the second column (i.e. `row[1]`). With this you can use the `requests` library to grab the HTML, and BeautifulSoup to parse out all strings.

Next you would need to use a regular expression to try and spot any email addresses inside the text. A simple search for `python email regular expression` should give you any number of possible solutions.

Next, for any emails that are found, write them as a row to an output CSV file:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import csv
import re

with open('input.csv', newline='') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)

    for row in csv_input:
        if row:
            company = row[0]
            url = row[1]
            print(f'Getting "{company}"')

            req = requests.get(url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(req.content, 'html.parser')

            for text in soup.stripped_strings:
                emails = re.findall(r'\b([A-Za-z0-9\.\+_-]+@[A-Za-z0-9\._-]+\.[a-zA-Z]*)\b', text)

                if emails:
                    csv_output.writerow([company, *emails])
```